# How can I append the word variable to my div?

Tags: javascript

I guess it will not let me because it is returning a string. The error I get is "Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'". How can I write this piece of code correctly?

```
getWord() {
    let words = ["Movies", "Series", "DC Comics", "Batman"];
    let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(word);
  }
```

Comment: You want `div.textContent = word;` instead, or create a text node first "in between" the div and word.

Comment: Thank you, it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `div.innerText = word`. Because you are trying to insert a String as a node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the `div.appendChild()` so that you could change the styling or element tag name of the text node in the future, you could create a text node and append it to the div instead, like so:

```
var text = document.createTextNode(word);
div.appendChild(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example you trying append string in the element, it's not correct, an argument for appendChild method should be element, for example:

```
const parent = document.createElement("div");
parent.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```

For your case, when you need to add content to the element, you should use textNode:

```
const title = document.createElement("H1");
const text = document.createTextNode("Movies");
title.appendChild(text);
```

Or:

```
const title = document.createElement("H1");
title.textContent = "Series";
```